# Grid divs without blanks

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm making a grid Wordpress theme with divs. But after three divs, there is a blank before the forth appears. This is due to the different heights. How can I make the divs so there is no blank area? You can see a preview of how it looks [here](http://inmyownview.com).

The css is:

```
#wrapper #frontpage .box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 380px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font: 100 12.5px 'Helvetica';
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}#wrapper #frontpage .box:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The html is a query of nine posts.

```
<div class="box">
    Content here
</div>
```

Comment: your design looks similar to pinterest's layout -- there's a good [tutorial on the CSS here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css3 - columns` Then You can display your divs in 3 columns and there are no white spaces between it.

[css3 - columns on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp)